# Weird date display on Windows Live Calendar task view

Tags: outlook.com, office-365, outlook.com-calendar

In the Task view within Windows Live Calendar, this is how my to-do items appear:

[image]

What is not user friendly about the `Sat DD/10` is that it could be any Saturday in the month of October. Why the "DD"?

Can I do something about this?

Comment: It could be just a glitch (`DD` looks like DayDay, as in DD/MM/YYYY).

Comment: Yup, that was my first guess too. It's quite a glaring glitch- one that's been around ever since they transitioned to the new interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue now seems to have been resolved. The date is displayed as follows:

[image]